# Swapping values between two pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can I swap values in a dataframe based on a defined condition?

Given:

```
DF[['Exchange','predictions']]

Exchange    predictions
0   PINK    <UNK>
1   PINK    <UNK>
2   PINK    <UNK>
3   PINK    <UNK>
4   PINK    <UNK>
... ... ...
490541  NASDAQ  PINK
490542  NaN PINK
490543  NASDAQ  PINK
490544  NaN PINK
490545  NASDAQ  PINK
```

I would like Exchange replaced with value in predictions only if Exchange value is NaN and Prediction value is not < UNK >.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `fillna` with partial condition `Series`

```
df.Exchange.fillna(df.loc[df['predictions'].ne('<UNK>'), 'predictions'], inplace=True)
df
Out[210]: 
       Exchange predictions
0          PINK       <UNK>
1          PINK       <UNK>
2          PINK       <UNK>
3          PINK       <UNK>
4          PINK       <UNK>
         ...         ...
490541   NASDAQ        PINK
490542     PINK        PINK
490543   NASDAQ        PINK
490544     PINK        PINK
490545   NASDAQ        PINK
```

Comment: worked perfectly. I am not sure what that command does..I know fillna just not the others..I'll look up 'ne' - thanks

Comment: @Lostsoul yw :-) happy coding ~